# any rules for using user variables in ssis

Tags: ssis

SSIS newbie question:

I have found different usages of a user variable and hence the confusion.

I have defined a user variable customerName.

In some places, (e.g. Script Task Editor's ReadOnlyVariables, it being referred as User::customerName since there is no option to select customerName.

Then in Script Task (Edit script), I see that its being referred as

```
 string custName = Dts.Variables["customerName"].Value.ToString();
```

and not as

```
 string custName = Dts.Variables["User::customerName"].Value.String();
```

Where and how does this work? Is there any rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either syntax should be acceptable in a script task. To further complicate matters, you could also reference it as `string custName = Dts.Variables[0].Value.ToString();`

The `User` bit refers to the namespace of an SSIS Variable. By default, you can access Variables in the System and User namespace but nothing prevents you from creating variables in a different spaace.

You're also going to run into `@[User::customerName]` syntax.